# Rails 3: ActiveRecord query with :includes only returns results that have related values in included table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got a model (a `Feature`) that can have many `Assets`. These `Assets` each have an `issue_date`. I'm struggling with what seems like a simple ActiveRecord query to **find all `Features` and their `Assets` with an `issue_date` of tomorrow, regardless of if there are `Assets` or not** — preferably with one query.

Here's my query right now.

```
Feature.includes(:assets).where(:assets => { :issue_date => Date.tomorrow })
```

Unfortunately, this returns only the `Features` that have `Assets` with an `issue_date` of tomorrow. Even stranger, the generated SQL looks like this (tomorrow's obviously the 19th).

```
SELECT `features`.* FROM `features`  WHERE `assets`.`issue_date` = '2011-08-19'
```

Shouldn't this have an `LEFT JOIN` in there somewhere? That's the sort of thing I'm going for. Using `joins` instead of `includes` does an `INNER JOIN`, but that's not what I want. Strangely enough, it seems like I'm getting an `INNER JOIN`-type of behavior. When I run that `includes` query above, the actual SQL that's spit out looks something like this...

```
SELECT `features`.`id` AS t0_r0, `features`.`property_id` AS t0_r1,
    // every other column from features truncated for sanity
    `assets`.`feature_id` AS t1_r1, `assets`.`asset_type` AS t1_r2,
    // all other asset columns truncated for sanity
FROM `features`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `assets` ON `assets`.`feature_id` = `features`.`id`
WHERE `assets`.`issue_date` = '2011-08-19'
```

Which **looks** like it should work right but it doesn't. I get *only* the `Features` that have `Assets` with an `issue_date` of tomorrow. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried the older, Rails v2 way of doing it…

```
Feature.find(:all,
             :include => :assets,
             :conditions => ['assets.issue_date = ?', Date.tomorrow])
```

Which gives me the same results. There's one `Feature` I know that doesn't have any `Assets` for tomorrow, and it's not in that list.

I've also poked around and found similar questions, but I couldn't seem to find one that explained this opposite behavior I'm seeing.

**Edit**: I'm *so* close. This gets me all the `Feature` objects.

```
Feature.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN assets on assets.feature_id = feature.id AND asset.issue_date = #{Date.tomorrow}")
```

It does **not**, however, get me the matching `Assets` bundled into the object. With `feature` as a returned item in the query, `feature.assets` makes another call to the database, which I don't want. I want `feature.assets` to return only those I've specified in that `LEFT OUTER JOIN` call. What else do I need to do to my query?

Comment: If issue_date is a field in the asset table, how are you expecting a query for a specific issue_date to ever return a feature that doesn't have any assets?

Comment: I apologize if my post isn't clear in that regard. I want a list of all `Features` as well as `Assets` for a certain date **if** such `Assets` exist; otherwise, just the `Feature`.

Comment: Oh sorry I understand, you did explain it but I think I got lost reading the rails-generated query.  The issue_date is a query for the outer join, rather than a query on the result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought this would get me what I needed, but it doesn't. Calling `feature.assets` (with `feature` as an item returned in my query) does another query to look for all `assets` related to that `feature`.

```
Feature.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN assets on assets.feature_id = feature.id AND asset.issue_date = #{Date.tomorrow}")
```

**So here's what does work. Seems a little cleaner, too.** My `Feature` model already has a `has_many :assets` set on it. I've set up *another* association with `has_many :tomorrows_assets` that points to `Assets`, but with a condition on it. Then, when I ask for `Feature.all` or `Feature.name_of_scope`, I can specify `.includes(:tomorrows_assets)`. Winner winner, chicken dinner.

```
has_many :tomorrows_assets,
  :class_name => "Asset",
  :readonly => true, 
  :conditions => "issue_date = '#{Date.tomorrow.to_s}'"
```

I can successfully query `Features` and get just what I need included with it, only if it matches the specified criteria (and I've set `:readonly` because I know I'll never want to edit `Assets` like this). Here's an IRB session that shows the magic.

```
features = Feature.includes(:tomorrows_assets)
feature1 = features.find_all{ |f| f.name == 'This Feature Has Assets' }.first
feature1.tomorrows_assets
=> [#<Asset id:1>, #<Asset id:2>]

feature2 = features.find_all{ |f| f.name == 'This One Does Not' }.first
feature2.tomorrows_assets
=> []
```

And all in only *two* SQL queries.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem and managed to solve it using the following query;

```
Feature.includes(:assets).where('asset.id IS NULL OR asset.issue_date = ?', Date.tomorrow)
```

This will load all features, regardless of whether it has any assets. Calling feature.asset will return an array of assets if available without running another query

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the SQL for outer joins yourself, the `joins` method only uses inner joins.

```
Feature.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN assets ON assets.feature_id = features.id").
where(:assets => {:issue_date => Date.tomorrow})
```

Comment: This query also leaves out the `Features` that don't have any `Assets` that match the `Asset` criteria. What about if I could specify the issue_date criteria inside the `joins` string? Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Feature.joins( :assets ).where( :issue_date => Date.tomorrow );
```

The guide here suggests the includes method is used to reduce the number of queries on a secondary table, rather than to join the two tables in the way you're attempting.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Using your query complains that `asset_type` isn't part of `Features`, so I reworded the last `where` clause to be wrapped around a hash for `assets` (like the last part of my query). Running it performs an `INNER JOIN` and I get the same results as above. What it seems that I need is a way to specify conditions to match on the `OUTER JOIN` directly.